# Understanding だったところに?

Tags: grammar, phrases

> だが、改変後の折紙の意識が『士道への思い三〇パーセント:節度七〇パーセント』**だったところに**、『士道への思い一二〇パーセント』が足されたなら、バランスも崩壊してしまおうというものだった。

Hi. What does the bold ところ mean? And why is past form だった used there? (Rather than present form である, for example)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

ところ refers to a "place" either in a concrete or abstract manner. This means it can refer to a a point in time, a physical place, or a part or portion of something. I think you understand this. Your sentence is referring to a point in time.

Here, だった and である is just modifying the point in time being referred to. であるところ would be a "non-past point in time" while だったところ refers to a point in time in the past. I think what is confusing you is how ところ is being used. For example, if we just replace ところ with 時, it would mean almost the same thing:

> 学生だった時 
> 学生だったところ (sounds a bit odd) 
> When I **was** a student.

> 学生である時 
> 学生であるところ (sounds a bit odd) 
> When I (**am** / will be) a student.

学生である and 学生だった are just modifying the noun that comes after it, which, in your case is ところ. So, だったところに would mean something along the lines of "when it was (in a certain state)".

Comment: I'm a little confused. You're explaining ところ but for the two examples you've given you say they sound unnatural. Did you mean this? If so, could you explain why please? I think I'm missing something important.

Comment: @user3856370 Sorry, maybe I should have made some clarification. I might be wrong (not a native speaker), but imo, if you are talking about "when you were a student" it sounds a bit odd to me to use ところ instead of ころ or 時, although it does seem grammatically sound.